Interpretation of Amulet from Moroccan Rabbi
Rabbi Rafael Ochana (1850-1906), born in Morocco, wrote a book called Mareh HaYeladim (1899?) that has the following design for an amulet, as protection from demons (on p.50, kaf-hey in book):

Can someone explain the words/letters and the significance of their arrangement? Magen David and Shmo Shaday are clear, and יקוק is a deliberate misspelling of Hashem's name. But I wasn't sure what these mean?
באב
קבול כסן
כסאן כסאבן
And what the letters around the Star of David signify?
Thank you.

I am using a dictionary of Syriac, which is close in meaning to Arabic. I could be mistaken. The letters around Magen David spell טפטף י-ה - make noise Hashem (plea), clatter, do not be silent. I.e. outside of the grave (symbolized by Magen David) frighten the demons.
Inside the grave:
באב - entrance/gate (for father is incorrect).
קבוֹל כסן - accept (with gratitude) the covered (likely several people)
כסאן כסאבן - honor/distingush them like old people (or a gift (sent in honor) at the time of their old age)

thank you. did you mean "distinguish" them like old people? what does distinguish mean here? is it like sanctify, or lekadesh in Hebrew?

@user99658 the root כסא has also meaning "mark"; in Hebrew it's chair throne. Perhaps a better translation is "honor".
